# How to Connect SIMCA online with Databricks?

Tags: databricks

Our company has recently adopted SIMCA online for data analytics.
I am looking to transfer data from Databricks to SIMCA online.
Has anyone attempted to connect Databricks with SIMCA online before?

According to SIMCA online, it can connect with an ODBC driver as long as the data source supports standard SQL. However, I am unsure of the steps required to establish a connection between Databricks and SIMCA online. Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

#SIMCA #Databricks #SimcaOnline

Answer (score 1):

If it supports connection via ODBC or JDBC then you can get ODBC or JDBC driver, and then get connection parameters as per [Databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/jdbc-odbc-bi.html) and then configure ODBC connection on SIMCA side as per their documentation.